# Export to PDF changing ticks color

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I'm exporting several images like

```
Export["path.pdf", fig, "PDF"]
```

The output, however, have the Automatic gray coloured tick labels changed to Black. This does not happen if I export in png, for instance.

How to export in pdf without altering the ticks labels style?

**Edit:** This is the Mathematica output:

[image]

This is the pdf output:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should show the .pdf file and the output as it appears in the notebook; it is hard to answer this question otherwise... Use a screenshot.

Comment: @mattiav27 edited! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify the `FrameTicksStyle` explicitly:

```
Plot[ Sin[x] , { x , 0 , 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None , 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Gray]]
Export[ "/tmp/1.pdf" , % , "PDF"]
```

Content of `/tmp/1.pdf`:

[image]

This worked for me with Mathematica 13.2.0 on Linux.  Without `FrameTicksStyle` I was getting gray ticks inside the Mathematica frontend and black in the exported pdf.